# revoke function from google-api-python-client

Tags: django, google-api, google-api-python-client

I am creating a logout function from a django app using the built in revoke method from google-api-python-client but it doesn't seem to work. Here is my code.

```
def google_logout(request, user_id = None):
    storage = Storage(CredentialsModel, 'id', user_id, 'credential')
    credential = storage.get()

    if credential is not None:
        cr_json = credential.to_json()
        credential = credential.new_from_json(cr_json)

        http = httplib2.Http()
        http = credential.authorize(http)

        try:
        # Don't know yet why this is always raising an exception.
            credential.revoke(http)
            storage.delete()
        except TokenRevokeError:
            return HttpResponseBadRequest('Invalid Token.')
    else:
        return redirect('authentication:google_login')
```

This was working when I am using django 1.4.5 but then I needed to upgrade to 1.5.1 and now it is not working. Is this a django problem? I bet not. Please help.

P.S. I know that I can revoke the token by manually passing the access_token to this url https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token={token} but I want to use the method provided in the api.

Comment: If you remove the try:except around `TokenRevokeError`, you should get a more detailed error message. Can you try that and see if it helps diagnose the error?

Comment: I've tried and it seems that I don't have a refresh token saved in my credentials object. I wonder why is it like that though it is written in the **client.py** `self.params = {'access_type': 'offline', 'response_type': 'code',}`

Comment: I have the same problem, @PhilamerSune, the `access_type` is set to `offline` (via the same flow constructor in the API client, as you're using) but I apparently don't get a refresh token back in my credentials object. Not sure how to get around this....

Comment: Ah, resolved, using `approval_prompt`=`force`. Answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the `access_type` is set to `offline`, you might not get a refresh token back if you've received a refresh token in the past and didn't additionally send the query parameter `approval_prompt` parameter set to `force`.

This is particularly frustrating and likely to occur during debugging revocation. Because you're likely approving and deleting credentials frequently, sometimes Google might remember the approval and authorize without going through the forced approval process, in which case you won't get a refresh token, which the client API requires for revocation.